# using image path returned by drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, paging

am unable to use the path returned by drupal 7 for an image which was uploaded for custom content type. the path returned is as follow:

```
Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 6 [alt] => [title] => [width] => 464 [height] => 261 [uid] => 1 [filename] => _71135631_c0166859-snotty_child_with_a_cold-spl.jpg [uri] => public://_71135631_c0166859-snotty_child_with_a_cold-spl.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 22168 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1384797114 [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

but when using the vale of uri, the image is not shown.

any assistance appreciated.

regards,
a.ali

Comment: `but when using the vale of uri, the image is not shown.` -- That's not very descriptive. We do not have enough information to be able to help you. How do you access the value of URI? How do you display the image? Does your code output any errors?

Comment: @AmalMurali i use the uri in the 'src' attribute of img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such `uri`-fields in Drupal always refer to the internal data-storage logic, hence the `public://` at the beginning. Drupal uses [Image Styles](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/image#styles) for any images attached to content.

To retrieve the full URL for an image, you should use [`image_style_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7):

```
$imgPath = image_style_url('default', $object['und'][0]['uri']);
```

Comment: thank you for reply . the img still doesnt seem to show up . following html is produced:

<img src="http://localhost/drupal/?q=sites/default/files/styles/default/public/_71135631_c0166859-snotty_child_with_a_cold-spl.jpg&amp;itok=MTem__cb">

following php is used
echo image_style_url('default', $news[6]->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);

Comment: The path looks fine. But is Drupal running on `http://localhost/drupal/` or through a different domain? If it's not on `localhost` than the `base_url` probably isn't set correctly

Comment: drupal is on localhost/drupal